# Get date-wise report MWS api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, amazon-mws

I am using amazon MWS api and i am trying to request report of particular date so is this possible to request report of particular date. for exp i want     _GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_ALL_DATA_ report of three days before so is it possible to request it using date. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, please look at the MWS documentation for [Reports](https://developer.amazonservices.com/gp/mws/api.html/144-5921913-9461653?ie=UTF8&group=bde&section=reports&version=latest).  Choose a `ReportType` and then you can choose a `StartDate` and `EndDate`.   Then submit a [RequestReport](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_RequestReport.html) request.  Use the [C# Client Library](https://developer.amazonservices.com/doc/bde/reports/v20090101/cSharp.html/144-5921913-9461653) help show the way.  You'll need to understand the report request process, but it's all in the [documentation](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/index.html).